# Getting image for bundle product child products, currently returning placeholder

Tags: magento

### My problem:

I need to retrieve the main product image from a cut down product object which is supplied by the class: `Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Price_Index`

My code demonstrating the issue:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_options = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getOptions());

foreach($_options as $_option):
    $_selections = $_option->getSelections();

    foreach ($_option->getSelections() as $tmpsel) {
        var_dump($tmpsel->getImageUrl());
    }
```

Which returns my placeholder image:

`http://dev.dev/media/catalog/product/cache/7/image/265x/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/placeholder/default/logo_3.jpg`

### My horrible and hacky work around:

In order to get correct image Url, I have resorted to loading a completely new product object, which is terribly inefficient.

```
foreach ($_option->getSelections() as $tmpsel) {
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($tmpsel->getId());
    $image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');        
    var_dump($image."");
}
```

This returns correctly:
`http://dev.dev/media/catalog/product/cache/7/image/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/M/P/MP1428219-107-Main.jpg`

### What I want to do:

I want to be able to use the `catalog/image` helper with the selection ($tmpsel), but when I try I end up getting the placeholder image again.

```
foreach ($_option->getSelections() as $tmpsel) {
    $image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($tmpsel, 'image');      
    var_dump($image."");
}
```

### Extra Info:

*Anything I think of that could help I will add here*

#### Cut down product object includes some reference to image

```
  'small_image' => string '/M/P/MP1428219-107-Main.jpg'
  'thumbnail' => string '/M/P/MP1428219-107-Main.jpg'
```

#### Description of getSelection()

In: ./app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Resource/Price/Index.php

`* Retrieve bundle options with selections and prices by product`

The function uses low level SQL to generate the collection, so I can always extend it to add options if needed, not sure which options though.

---

Thank you for reading, hope someone can give me a good way of doing this, will keep updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init() method require a product object

```
init(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $attributeName, $imageFile=null)
```

Try

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($tmpsel, 'small_image')->resize(40,40); ?>
```

You do not have 'image' but you do have 'small_image' attribute

See [Magento - how to retrieve bundled option images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318915/magento-how-to-retreive-bundled-option-images)

Answer (score 1):

To get the full web address you can use this code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());
```

The limitation is that bring only the main image.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, I guess I can thank you stack overflow for making me write my thoughts down.

After comparing the full product object and the semi product object I can see that I was calling the incorrect attribute name for `catalog/image`

```
$image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($tmpsel, 'image');
```

Should have been

```
$image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($tmpsel, 'small_image');
```